# How can I delete a row that has only null value in each column?

Tags: mysql

I would like to know how can I delete a row that has only null values in each column.

```
CREATE TABLE taxes 
( 
    id int(11) NOT NULL, 
    Name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    Person varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    Price int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    Year varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This is my table. I haven't tried anything because I don't know what could cause this.

Actually, issue occurred after I altered a table in order to add another column.

After the column was added, an empty row appeared and if I try to modify that row, another one pops out.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: post what you have tried

Comment: CREATE TABLE `taxes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Person` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Year` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

This is my table. I haven't tried anything because I don't know what could cause this.

Comment: I suppose Id has any value?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/xYnb2 
this is how my table looks like. And i want to get rid of the last row.

Answer (score 0):

First try:

```
SELECT Id
FROM   taxes
WHERE  Name IS NULL
AND    Person IS NULL
AND    Price IS NULL 
AND    Year IS NULL;
```

If it returns affected rows, then use DELETE.

```
DELETE FROM   taxes
WHERE  Id IN (SELECT Id
              FROM   taxes
              WHERE  Name IS NULL
              AND    Person IS NULL
              AND    Price IS NULL 
              AND    Year IS NULL);
```

OR

```
DELETE FROM   taxes
WHERE  Name IS NULL
AND    Person IS NULL
AND    Price IS NULL 
AND    Year IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can COALESCE and then test if a row has all NULL values.
First, try this to test:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
WHERE COALESCE(column1,column2,column3) IS NULL
```

Then, if that returns everything you want, go ahead and DELETE:

```
DELETE FROM yourtable
WHERE COALESCE(column1,column2,column3) IS NULL
```

Comment: The DELETE query does not affect any rows .

Comment: I tested and verified that this solution does work. When you use the SELECT * FROM yourtable, does it show you the results you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The SELECT * FROM table does show it's content. However, I managed to discover the thing that bothered me. I created two different tables, one with 'NOT NULL' and one with 'DEFAULT NULL'. I noticed that the table that contains 'NOT NULL' for columns does create an extra row full of 'NULL' values and the table that contains 'DEFAULT NULL' does not do that. Can anyone explain to me why? What's the difference beetween them?

Table 1 :CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Animal` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Size` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

Table 2: CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CITY` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL
);